# Clear Cookies of WebView in Titanium

Tags: webview, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I am loading a website in Titanium webview. I can see all the cookies without any issue. Now I want to delete all the cookies.

Some forum have mentioned that we have to find '\Library\Cookies' folder and manually delete it, but I am worried if it delete entire Cookies. I want to delete cookies related to the webview. Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a few methods in titanium that can help to **clear cookies**, have a look at the below methods which can help you

[Titanium.Network.removeHTTPCookie](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network-method-removeHTTPCookie), [Titanium.Network.removeHTTPCookiesForDomain](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network-method-removeHTTPCookiesForDomain), [Titanium.Network.removeAllHTTPCookies](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network-method-removeAllHTTPCookies), [Titanium.Network.removeSystemCookie](http://Titanium.Network.removeSystemCookie), [Titanium.Network.removeAllSystemCookies](http://Titanium.Network.removeAllSystemCookies)

Let me know if any of that help you.

## EDIT (For Android)

You can try the `Titanium.Network.removeSystemCookie` or `Titanium.Network.removeAllSystemCookies`, as in Android `webView` saves its cookies in system cookie store and it is not shared with the `Titanium.Network.HTTPClient` cookie store.

**Good Luck, cheers**

**Ashish Sebastian**

Comment: Thanks Ashish for your reply. Above method are working fine in iPhone but its not working in Android. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @ManojKushwaha : Have you tried removing the `systemCookie`, as in Android the webview uses the system cookies and it is not shared with the `Titanium.Network.HTTPClient`. Hope this helps in android also.